# How to get a specific content type response

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-groups-settings

It seems that whatever I throw at google api I will always get the same type of content (JSON or XML). For example:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups/get

I want to get a JSON response about groups settings (GET https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/groupUniqueId) - I set headers to accept `json` and with content type to `application/json`. I should get JSON but I still get an XML. For other endpoints I get JSON by default but I can't get an XML one.

Question is - what should I do to get what I want (JSON response for https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups/get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a query parameter of `?alt=json` to set the preferred response.